# How to align fraction with a hat in the denominator

Tags: vertical-alignment

When I write

```
\frac{1}{f} \frac{1}{\hat{f}}
```

I get the following

[image]

I would like the two f's to be vertically aligned, but instead the second one dips lower. Is there something like \phantom to put an invisible hat on the first f?

In this particular example I could just write

```
\frac{1}{f \hat{f}}
```

which would align the f's, but this is a simplification of a more complicated example where it is clearer to separate the content into two fractions.

Comment: You might use  `\frac{1}{f\vphantom{\hat{f}}}`.

Comment: Alas, \mathstrut doesn't quite get you there.

Answer (score 7):

I can propose a new command that takes both fractions as arguments and typesets them with suitable phantoms. The optional argument is for something to be set in between the two fractions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\linkedfracs}[5][]{%
  \frac{#2\vphantom{#4}}{#3\vphantom{#5}}%
  #1%
  \frac{#4\vphantom{#2}}{#5\vphantom{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\linkedfracs{1}{f}{1}{\hat{f}}
\qquad
\linkedfracs[+]{1}{f}{1}{\hat{f}}
\qquad
\linkedfracs[-]{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{3}{x}{y}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Best I could do was define a macro that would kludge it together. There must be a better way for deciding the vertical offset.

**Edit:** Turns out I completely missread your questions, and worked on the wrong alignment! I have implemented Bernard's suggestion here as \nohat{}

[image: nohat]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}

\newcommand\fhat{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0.61ex}{f}{\hat{~}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}

\newcommand\nohat[1]{#1\vphantom{\hat{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[
    \frac{1}{\fhat} \frac{1}{\hat{f}} \frac{1}{f\vphantom{\hat{f}}} \frac{1}{\nohat{f}}
\]
  
\end{document}
```